# find a file and truncate it

Tags: find

I'm simply trying to find a single log file and truncate it. Why won't this work?

```
find ${listener}/tracefiles/${listener}.log -exec cp /dev/null '{}'\;
```

This returns an error: `find: missing argument to`-exec'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be whitespace in front of the `;`:

```
find "${listener}/tracefiles/${listener}.log" -exec cp /dev/null {} \;
```

But it doesn't make any sense to call `find -exec` for a single file. Why don't you use

```
test -f "${listener}/tracefiles/${listener}.log" &&
    cp /dev/null "${listener}/tracefiles/${listener}.log"
```

Comment: when i put the space in in front of the \ like so: find ${listener_loc}/trace/${listener_loc}.log -exec cp /dev/null {} \;  i get an error saying find: `{}/trace/{}.log': Not a directory

Comment: @ForeverAlone In your question you used `${listener}`, not `${listener_loc}`. What is the output of `echo "${listener_loc}"`?4

Comment: We're discussing this in [chat], if you're interested.

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple:

```
find ${listener}/tracefiles -name ${listener}.log -exec truncate -s0 {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not working because you need a space before the `\;`. Try this:

```
find ${listener}/tracefiles/${listener}.log -exec cp /dev/null '{}' \;
```

However, that's a needlessly complex way of truncating the file. First of all, since you apparently know the exact path of the file, all you need to do is:

```
> ${listener}/tracefiles/${listener}.log
```

If you're using `find` to avoid creating the file if it doesn't exist, you can try:

```
[ -e ${listener}/tracefiles/${listener}.log ] && > ${listener}/tracefiles/${listener}.log
```

If you really need `find` (if you have more than one file to work on), you can use

```
find ${listener}/tracefiles/${listener}.log -exec sh -c '> {}' \;
```

Or even:

```
find ${listener}/tracefiles/${listener}.log -exec printf '' {} \;
```

Comment: That's not the same if the file doesn't exist.

Comment: @HaukeLaging fair point, edited.

Comment: i want to use find in this case, because i'm using it in a loop and don't want to change directories. i used find ${listener}/tracefiles/${listener}.log -exec sh -c '> {}' \;  but it gave me this error even though i've used the exact same find command to do other things before.  find: `{}/trace/{}.log': Not a directory
{}

Comment: @ForeverAlone i) there's no reason to change directories, if that `find` command works, so will `> ${listener}/tracefiles/${listener}.log `; ii) that error message doesn't make much sense. I suggest you come into [/dev/chat/](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/dev-chat) and we can debug it there.